# Make a rotating gradient on a circle?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I'm trying to get a rotating gradient on a circle to follow-this mock-up.
[image: rotating gradient following line]

I've mocked up what I'm trying to do in a [a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/FPymt/).

For your convenience here's the code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var radius = 75;
var startAngle = 0// 1.1 * Math.PI;
var endAngle = 2.0 * Math.PI;//1.9 * Math.PI;
var counterClockwise = false;

context.beginPath();
var gradient = context.createLinearGradient(radius, radius, 0, 0);
gradient.addColorStop(0, '#3b749a');
gradient.addColorStop(1, '#FFFFFF');
context.lineWidth = 15;

context.arc(radius, radius, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);

context.strokeStyle = gradient;
context.stroke(gradient);
```

Now here's my challenge. No matter what I try I can't seem to get the gradient to follow the path. It seems to apply from whatever angle it desires, but not follow the path. What am I doing wrong?

Second, is it possible to get a rounded corner on one edge like the mockup?

### Follow-up question to the imperfect solution:

So it appears there's no way to stroke a path with a gradient, only to apply a gradient to the canvas which the path "cuts out." (And there's no "circle" gradient AFAIK in HTML5.)

Since the proposed solution requires drawing two elements, what's the best way to rotate/animate this? With one object/context, it appeared I could just grab that, transform and rotate. With two, do I need to render to an image object and rotate?

Comment: I discovered `context.lineCap = "round";` will round the corners of the circle.

Comment: I also improved upon the existing style by borrowing a technique from @Johan by drawing two lines on a circle. Its not an ideal solution but it appears there's no way to have a linear gradient follow the path. Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/FPymt/45/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was actually not that trivial. Perhaps there was an easier way to do this and I just took the hard approach. Or perhaps this is something newish.

What I did was I ended up drawing a gradient box inside of the circle. On an interval the circle changes its start and end points so that the gap rotates. While that happens, I recalculate the gradient box to fit into the new gap and then draw that on there. The result is a nice effect.

In this demo, I have set it up to cycle randomly over colors and different sizes in order to show what different spinners look like and to have some fun.

### **[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F53wW/)**

The meat of the operation is in this function:

```
function showSpinner(
 startAngle,endAngle,direction,radius,line,context,color,shadow)
{
 context.beginPath();
 var a = startAngle / Math.PI;
 a = a % 2;
 a = 2 - a;
 a *= Math.PI;
 var x = radius + Math.cos(a)*radius*1.7;
 var y = radius - Math.sin(a)*radius*1.7;
 var gradient = context.createLinearGradient(radius,radius,x,y);
 gradient.addColorStop(0.05, color);
 gradient.addColorStop(.60, '#FFFFFF');
 context.lineWidth = line;
 context.lineCap = "round";
 context.shadowBlur = 10;
 if( shadow === true )context.shadowColor = '#727272';
 context.arc(radius, radius, radius-line, startAngle, endAngle, direction);
 context.strokeStyle = gradient;
 context.stroke();
}
```

This function leverages the above drawing function in order to provide animation

```
function spinner(obj){
 var radius,line,color,shadow;
 if( obj && obj.hasOwnProperty("shadow") ){
  shadow = true;
 }else{ radius = 75; }
 if( obj && obj.hasOwnProperty("radius") ){
  radius = obj.radius;
 }else{ radius = 75; }
 if( obj && obj.hasOwnProperty("line") ){
  line = obj.line;
 }else{ line = 7; }
 var speed = {inc:0.04,loop:15};
 if( obj && obj.hasOwnProperty("speed") ){
  if( obj.speed == "slow" ){
   speed = {inc:0.02,loop:25};
  }
 }
 if( obj && obj.hasOwnProperty("color") ){
  color = obj.color;
 }else{ color = '#3b749a'; } 
 var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
 canvas.style.height = 2*(radius+line) + "px";
 canvas.style.width = 4*(radius+line) + "px";
 var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
 var startAngle,endAngle;
 var counterClockwise = false;
 var sa = 1.2;
 var ea = 0.85;

 var spinner = setInterval(function(){
   canvas.width = canvas.width;
   sa += speed.inc;
   ea += speed.inc;
   startAngle = sa * Math.PI;
   endAngle = ea * Math.PI;
   showSpinner(
     startAngle,
     endAngle,
     counterClockwise,
     radius,
     line,
     context,
     color, 
     shadow
   );
 },speed.loop);
 setTimeout(function(){ clearInterval(spinner);},15000);
 return spinner;
}
```

But all you really have to do to use this, is

```
spinner()
```

Pass in an argument if you would like. Your options are radius, line, color, shadow, and speed.

```
var obj = {};
obj.line = int - the size in pixels of the line width
obj.radius = int - the radius of the circle drawn (currently maxed at 75 for viewing, but you can always change the size of the canvas if you want)
obj.color = string - the color that the line of the spinner will be
obj.shadow = bool - show the shadow or don't show it
obj.speed = string - Only supports "slow" right now. Otherwise it will be fast
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not very elegant:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 67.5;
context.beginPath();
context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2.0 * Math.PI, false);
context.lineWidth = 15;
context.strokeStyle = '#3b749a';
context.stroke();

context.beginPath();
context.arc(x, y, radius, -Math.PI/2, Math.PI/2, false);
var gradient = context.createLinearGradient(0, y-radius, 0, y+radius);
gradient.addColorStop(0, '#3b749a');
gradient.addColorStop(0.5, '#FFFFFF');
gradient.addColorStop(1, '#3b749a');
context.lineWidth = 15;
context.strokeStyle = gradient;
context.stroke(gradient);
```

Comment: You're right! It doesn't seem very elegant. Can you help me understand why you did this the way did? When I get to my computer I'll try to improve on it.

Comment: Tbh it was the only way i could think of. I'm very new to js and this is the first thing i ever did in HTML but your q looked fun :D